# How to build Android Kiwi browser

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am new to android development and bit unsure how to build this project as the project structure doesn't seem to be "generic" Android Studio project. Any documentation etc would be really helpful.

Url to Kiwi Github repo: https://github.com/kiwibrowser/android

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked out Kiwi personally but because it is chromium based, I think https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md should help you out.